# Ukrainian.Enter US B1 B2 Visa, can I switch to C1D status entering US

Tags: change-purpose-of-travel, ukrainian-citizens

I am from Ukraine and I entered USA with B1/B2 visa. My friend brought me here for a couple of weeks just to have a little rest from the situation in Ukraine (a state of war).

Unexpectedly I have gotten a contract with a cruise line and I have to join the ship in the US. Am I allowed to do this in my situation?

I also have C1D visa.  With whom should I talk to about this? This is my first time in the US as a tourist and I have to join the ship in a few days. Will I get in trouble? Or will immigration be able to change my entered status from B1/B2 to C1/D?

Comment: There is a fairly costly change of status procedure.  I don't know whether it is available for those wishing to change from B status to C-1/D (furthermore, I don't know much about C-1/D).  Even if the change of status procedure is available, it's probably too time consuming (and you wouldn't be able to work before the change is approved), so your best bet might be to go briefly to Canada, Mexico, or the Caribbean so you can be reinspected by a US immigration officer for admission under your C-1/D visa.

Comment: On the other hand, it may not be necessary -- as I said, I don't know much about how D status works, but the C-1 part of the combination visa is to allow you to travel to the ship, which you can do on your B admission.

Comment: What  advice did the HR department at your new employers give you about your situation when you asked them?  Would they allow you to join the ship at the first non-USA port of call, if there is one?